# filter-backend in djando rest api

Tags: django-rest-framework

i am working with django rest api.can we use filter-backend to retrieve data between 2 dates,the dates are given as a url parameter.

```
class DotOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes = (GroupPermissionExternalApi,)
        serializer_class = dot_order_serializers.DotOrderSerializer
        queryset = dot_order_models.DotOrder.objects.all()
        filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, 
                       filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter,)
        search_fields = ('id', 'merchant__email', 'merchant__contact', 
                       'biker__name', 
                      'biker__contact',biker__datetime_created',
                       'biker__type')
        ordering_fields = '__all__'

        def list(self,request):
                start=request.GET.get('from_date')
                end=request.GET.get('to_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `DjangoFilterBackend` so you can create your own custom `filter_class` and use `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter`.

```
class DotOrderFilterSet(FilterSet):
    date_range = DateTimeFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = dot_order_models.DotOrder
        fields = ['date_range', ... ]
```

`fields` should contain also the rest of the fields from  DotOrder model that you want to filter on. And then add your filter class in the view:

```
class DotOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, ...)
    filter_class = DotOrderFilterSet
    ...
```

Your query parameter should be: `date_range_after` and `date_range_before`.
More details about the `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter` can be found [here](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html?highlight=between#datetimefromtorangefilter).